# Clickable modifier on Row not receiving events

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following page on which I'm trying to display a list of saved cards with the ability to add a new one. The last item in the column is an expandable one so that when clicked, the user can see a form for filling out card info in order to add a new card. This was working just fine yesterday, but I can't figure out why it's not working today.
The actual CardItem elements receive clicks just fine but the custom expandable one does not and neither does the ShadowWrapper parent nor the RaisedCard one.

Cards screen:

```
private data class CreditCard(val type: CreditCardTypes, val lastDigits: String)
 
@Composable
fun CardSelectionScreen(onCardSelected: () -> Unit) {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(vertical = 24.dp, horizontal = 16.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        var selectedCardIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        val cardList = listOf(
            CreditCard(CreditCardTypes.MASTERCARD, "3429"),
            CreditCard(CreditCardTypes.VISA, "3429"),
            CreditCard(CreditCardTypes.MASTERCARD, "3429")
        )
        TopBarPadding(true)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        RaisedCard() {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 20.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.please_select_a_card),
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(9.dp))
                for (i in cardList.indices) {
                    CreditCardItem(cardList[i],
                        isSelected = selectedCardIndex == i, onItemSelected = { ->
                            selectedCardIndex = i
                        })
                }
                ShadowWrapper( // This is the item's layout
                    cardElevation = 1.dp,
                    shadowElevation = 3.dp
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .animateContentSize()
                    ) {
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
                                .background(
                                    if (selectedCardIndex == cardList.size) colorResource(
                                        id = R.color.bottom_modal_drawer_background
                                    ) else Color.White
                                )
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp)
                                .clickable(
                                    indication = null,
                                    interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource()
                                ) { // this does not register at all, tried with Log.d
                                    selectedCardIndex = cardList.size
                                },
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_add_credit_card),
                                contentDescription = "Add credit card icon"
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(13.dp))
                            Text(
                                stringResource(id = R.string.new_card_addition),
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                                color = colorResource(id = R.color.Orange_100)
                            )
                        }
                        if (selectedCardIndex == cardList.size) {
                            Column(
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(
                                    horizontal = 16.dp
                                )
                            ) {
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(22.fixedDp()))
                                Text(
                                    text = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.add_credit_card_top_msg),
                                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.Black_100)
                                )
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                                InputField(label = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.owner_name))
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(18.fixedDp()))
                                InputField(label = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.credit_card_number))
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(18.fixedDp()))
                                Row() {
                                    Box(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .weight(1.5f)
                                    ) {
                                        InputField(label = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.expiration_date))
                                    }
                                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(6.fixedDp()))
                                    Box(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .weight(1f)
                                    ) {
                                        InputField(
                                            label = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.cvv),
                                            isPassword = true,
                                            placeholder = ""
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(34.fixedDp()))
                                Row() {
                                    MyCheckbox(
                                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 3.dp),
                                        isCheckedInitially = true
                                    )
                                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(13.dp))
                                    Text(
                                        stringResource(id = R.string.save_card_for_future_transactions),
                                        fontSize = 14.sp,
                                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.Black_100)
                                    )
                                }
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(22.fixedDp()))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
        MyButton(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.continue_text),
            MyButtonType.PRIMARY,
            onClick = { onCardSelected() }
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        AcceptedCardsFooter()
        BottomBarPadding(true)
    }
}
 
@Composable
private fun CreditCardItem(
    cardDetails: CreditCard,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    onItemSelected: () -> Unit
) {
    ShadowWrapper(cardElevation = 1.dp, shadowElevation = 3.dp) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
                .background(if (isSelected) colorResource(id = R.color.bottom_modal_drawer_background) else Color.White)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 15.dp)
                .clickable(indication = null, interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource()) {
                    onItemSelected()
                },
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                MyRadioButton(label = "", selected = isSelected)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(43.dp)
                        .height(33.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                        .background(colorResource(id = R.color.Grey_10))
                        .padding(horizontal = 6.dp, vertical = 7.dp)
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = cardDetails.type.icon),
                        contentDescription = "",
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.fixedDp()))
                Text(
                    text = "${cardDetails.type.prefix}****${cardDetails.lastDigits}",
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.Black_100)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RaisedCard.kt:

```
@Composable
fun RaisedCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mainBody: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(13.dp),
        elevation = 10.dp,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {
            mainBody()
        }
    }
}
```

ShadowWrapper.kt:

```
@Composable
fun ShadowWrapper(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    border: BorderStroke = BorderStroke(0.dp, Color.Transparent),
    cardElevation: Dp = 2.dp,
    shadowElevation: Dp = 1.dp,
    shadowShapeRadius: Dp = 6.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Card(
        elevation = cardElevation,
        border = border,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(shadowShapeRadius),
        modifier = modifier.shadow(shadowElevation, RoundedCornerShape(shadowShapeRadius)).wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your issue, probably because other parts of your application are triggering additional recompositions. However the cause is most likely that you forget to `remember` your `MutableInteractionSource`s.

Like this:

```
otherModifiers.clickable(
    indication = null,
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
) { // this does not register at all, tried with Log.d
    selectedCardIndex = cardList.size
}
```

If you do not wrap `MutableInteractionSource` in a `remember`, a new instance is created on every recomposition, so state like a previous touch events is lost

Comment: This fixed the issue! I would have never thought about this. Do you happen to know if this is documented somewhere in the official documentation?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/interaction/MutableInteractionSource
"This instance should be `remember`ed before it is passed to other components that consume it."

Comment: Samples can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/compose/foundation/foundation/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/samples/InteractionSourceSample.kt) as well

Comment: Thank you the docs covered everything. I had no idea about this, awesome answer!